# How do I print the last element of an array in c

Tags: c, arrays

I want to detect the last element of an array of integer in C code.
Otherwise i need to stop handling array data when the array element is empty.
really my array have a maximum size fixed  and it was filled from an external file so i dont know when it stop filling the array.

Comment: If you have an actual array and not a pointer, the number of elements in the array could be calculated by using `sizeof array / sizeof array[0]`. From that you can get the last index. If, on the other hand, you only have a pointer (like if the array was passed to a function) then there is no way of getting its size.

Comment: really my array have a maximum size fixed  and it was fillen from an external file so i dont know when it stop filling the array.

Comment: If you fill the array from a file, then you must have an index that is the next element in the array to be initialized from the value in the file, right? When you're done with the file, that index should be the "size" of the array, the number of elements you have initialized.

Comment: For the sake of avoiding misunderstandings, you might like to show us the related code.

Comment: @Lundin the problem is that that array is not all filled so i wanted to know the number of element that filled..thats what i mean it

Answer (score 12):

Last element is in position

```
sizeof(array)/sizeof(array[0]) - 1
```

Answer (score 9):

There is no defined term as empty array

Your array will always hold some value even if you dont initialize it explicitly

You need to define in your application how will you term it as empty may be by considering if its(element of array) value is 0 or some other value

Comment: i want to say empty element in array that is initialized with a fix size

Comment: "*There is no defined term as empty array*" or empty array element.

Comment: so when i declared an array and did not fill it and i did not used it.. what it should be in the array ?

Comment: @gerrard2461: "*what it should be in the array?*" indetermined content. Reading this content might very well provoke the infamous Undefined Behaviour. Always "initialise" your variables *before* reading them for the first time.

Answer (score 4):

If you don't explicitly know the size of your array, you could calculate it by using the `sizeof` operator:

```
size_t size = sizeof(your_array) / sizeof(your_array[0]);
```

This calculates the total size in bytes of the array and divides it by the size of one element (you can also use `sizeof(int)` in your case, but if you change the type of your array this will probably break).

Then, you can simply loop over the array's elements like so:

```
for(size_t i = 0; i < size; ++i)
    printf("%d\n", your_array[i]);
```

Comment: `If you have an array without it's size` How can you have an array without size?

Comment: I meant "if you don't explicitly know its size". I will change this sentence to be more accurate.

Comment: i know the maximum size but dont know the number of element in this aray

Comment: I don't understand, what do you mean by the maximum size? Isn't it the number of element in the array?

Comment: no i initialized my array with: int array [128] and it is filled from a file so i dont know the number of element filled thats what i mean

Comment: Alright, then how do you fill it from the file? Because you must have some sort of loop or index that will hint you on the actual size of the array.

Answer (score 3):

Why not you use the simple `n-1` method!

Just let a variable `l`

where `l = arr[n - 1];`

then `printf(l)` ...

Quite simple I guess...