# Is there a quick way to get the last element that was put in an array?

Tags: arrays, c, char, fgets, c-strings

I use an `fgets` to read from `stdin` a line and save it in a `char` array, I would like to get the last letter of the line i wrote , which should be in the array before `\n`and `\0`.

For example if i have a `char line[10]` and write on the terminal `1stLine`, is there a fast way to get the letter `e` rather than just cycling to it?

I saw this post [How do I print the last element of an array in c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44130392/how-do-i-print-the-last-element-of-an-array-in-c) but I think it doesn't work for me, even if I just create the array without filling it with `fgets` , `sizeof line` is already 10 because the array already has something in it

I know it's not java and I can't just  `.giveMeLastItem()`, but I wonder if there is a smarter way than to cycle until the char before the `\n` to get the last letter I wrote

code is something like

```
char command[6];
fgets(command,6,stdin);
```

Comment: Can you show us your actual code, please? It sounds like you just want `x[strlen(x) - 1]`...

Comment: @AKX ... which backstage probably also iterates through the chararacters in that array and then does some additional dereferencing.

Comment: @Yunnosch Yeah, it does. C strings don't store their lengths like Pascal strings do.

Comment: @AKX unless stripped of the `\n` from `fgets()`, it'll always return `\n`. Just saying.

Comment: @SouravGhosh Sure, in which case OP wants `- 2`. :shrug:

Comment: `x[strlen(x) - 1]` is UB if the string is empty

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know the sentinel value, ex: `\0` (or `\n` ,or any value for that matter), and you want the value of the element immediately preceding to that, you can

- use [`strchr()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strchr) to find out the position of the sentinel and
- get the address of `retPtr-1` and dereference to get the value you want.

Comment: Plus making sure that `retPtr` isn't the first element of the array.

Comment: @Shawn Yes, surely that.

Answer (score 2):

Once you have only the array, there is no other way to do this. You could use `strlen(line)` and then get the last characters position based on this index, but this basically does exactly the same (loop over the array).

```
char lastChar = line[strlen(line)-1];
```

This has time-complexity of O(n), where n is the input length.

You can change the input method to a char by char input and count the length or store the last input. Every O(1) method like this uses O(n) time before (like n times O(1) for every character you read). But unless you have to really speed optimize (and you don't, when you work with user input) should just loop over the array by using a function like `strlen(line)` (and store the result, when you use it multiple times).

EDIT:
The `strchr()` function Sourav Ghosh mentioned, does exactly the same, but you can/must specify the termination character.

Comment: `line[strlen(line)-1]` may have undefined behavior in pathological cases where the input file has embedded null bytes.

Comment: Reading the input one byte at a time will be much more costly than reading a full line and calling `strlen()`, `strchr()` or even `strcspn()` on the resulting array.

Answer (score 2):

There are many different ways to inspect the line read by `fgets()`:

- first you should check the return value of `fgets()`: a return value of `NULL` means either the end of file was reached or some sort of error occurred and the contents of the target array is undefined. It is also advisable to use a longer array.

  ```
    char command[80];
    if (fgets(command, sizeof command, stdin) == NULL) {
        // end of file or read error
        return -1;
    }
  ```
- you can count the number of characters with `len = strlen(command)` and if this length os not zero(*), `command[len - 1]` is the last character read from the file, which should be a `'\n'` if the line has less than 5 bytes. Stripping the newline requires a test:

  ```
    size_t len = strlen(command);
    if (len > 0 && command[len - 1] == '\n')
        command[--len] = '\0';
  ```
- you can use `strchr()` to locate the newline, if present with `char *p strchr(command, '\n');` If a newline is present, you can strip it this way:

  ```
    char *p = strchar(command, '\n');
    if (p != NULL)
        *p = '\0';
  ```
- you can also count the number of characters no in the set `"\n"` with `pos = strcspn(command, "\n")`. `pos` will point to the newline or to the null terminator. Hence you can strip the trailing newline with:

  ```
    command[strcspn(command, "\n")] = '\0';  // strip the newline if any
  ```
- you can also write a simple loop:

  ```
    char *p = command;
    while (*p && *p != '\n')
        p++;
    *p = '\n'; // strip the newline if any
  ```

---

(*) `strlen(command)` can return `0` if the file contains an embedded null character at the beginning of a line. The null byte is treated like an ordinary character by `fgets()`, which continues reading bytes into the array until either `size - 1` bytes have been read or a newline has been read.

Answer (score 1):

A straightforward approach can look the following way

```
char last_letter = command[ strcspn( command, "\n" ) - 1 ];
```

provided that the string is not empty or contains just the new line character `'\n'`.

Here is a demonstrative progarm.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) 
{
    enum { N = 10 };
    char command[N];
    
    while ( fgets( command, N, stdin ) && command[0] != '\n' )
    {
        char last_letter = command[ strcspn( command, "\n" ) - 1 ];
        printf( "%c ", last_letter );
    }
    
    putchar( '\n' );
    
    return 0;
}
```

If to enter the following sequence of strings

```
Is
there
a
quick
way
to
get
the
last
element
that
was
put
in
an
array?
```

then the output will be

```
s e a k y o t e t t t s t n n ?
```

Answer (score 1):

The fastest way is to keep an array of references like this:

```
long ref[]
```

and ref[x] to contain the file offset of the last character of the xth line.  Having this reference saved at the beginning of the file you will do something like:

```
fseek(n*sizeof(long))
long ref = read_long()
fseek(ref)
read_char()
```

I think this is the fastest way to read the last character at the end of the nth line.

Answer (score 1):

Beside the other good examples.

Another way is using `fscanf()`/`scanf()` and the `%n` format specifier to write to an argument the amount of read characters so far after you have input the string.

Then you subtract this number by one and use it as an index to `command`:

```
char command[6];
int n = 0;

if (fscanf(stdin, "%5[^\n]" "%n", command, &n) != 1)
{
    fputs("Error at input!", stderr);
    // error routine.
}

getchar();

if (n != 0)
{
    char last_letter = command[n-1];
}
```

---

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void)
{
    char command[6];
    int n = 0;

    if (fscanf(stdin, "%5[^\n]" "%n", command, &n) != 1)
    {
        fputs("Error at input!", stderr);
        // error routine.
    }

    getchar();
    
    if (n != 0)
    {
        char last_letter = command[n-1];
        putchar(last_letter);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Execution:

```
./a.out
hello
o
```

Comment: The `fscanf()` version will fail on empty lines because the `%[^\n]` specification will not match any byte from the input.

Comment: @chqrlie Corrected I think. Now if `n == 0` it goes into the error routine.

Comment: No, when the first conversion fails, the `%n` is never reached. Furthermore `n` cannot be set to `0` by `fscanf()` because each conversion specifier must match at least one byte. Finally, an empty line might not be an error, although it does not have a *last* printable character.

Comment: @chqrlie So, now I think I fixed all of these issues. Initialized `n` to `0` and don't treat it as error. Also fetched the abandoned newline from `stdin`. Of course one could still argue that a newline can't be input in the array but if that is an desired aspect, I recommend using just `fgets` instead.

Comment: @chqrlie I have to do more investigation about "*because each conversion specifier must match at least one byte.*" - That's still quite a little unclear to me as `n` is of type `char` which is always one byte, but I might think in the wrong direction...

Comment: `%5[^\n]` cannot match 0 characters from the input. Hence on an empty line, that starts with a `\n`, `fscanf()` fails and returns `0`. The `%n` conversion is not handled and `n`, which has type `int` as expected, is not modified.

Answer (score 1):

I did a quick test of the three mentioned methods of reading a line from a stream and measuring its length. I read /usr/share/dict/words 100 times and measured with clock()/1000:

```
fgets + strlen = 420
getc = 510
fscanf with " 100[^\n]%n" = 940
```

This makes sense as fgets and strlen just do 2 calls, getc does a call per character, and fscanf may do one call but has a lot of machinery to set up for processing complex formats, so a lot more overhead.  Note the added space in the fscanf format to skip the newline left from the previous line.

Comment: thank you, i could never do that it's useful to know this speed